# Angular 2 insert a dynamic component into a specific element

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-cli

I know this question has been asked several times before (some answers have used deprecated api's) but i’m really struggling understanding how insert a dynamic component into a specific element in my template.

I'm using rc-5.

I have an infinite scrolling list, which should create and insert new advert components each time the load event is fired.

The problem I have is that I can only insert new components next to my target element and what I want to do is append to the list inside my target element.

The code I have currently is shown below:

```
//This is my target
@ViewChild('adList', {read: ViewContainerRef}) adList:ViewContainerRef;
private _componentReference: ComponentRef<AdvertisementComponent>;
```

Then I have a function to load adverts

```
loadAdContent(): void {
    this._adsSubscription = this._adService.getAdvertisments().subscribe((ads) => {
      if(ads.error){
        if(ads.error === ErrorCode.NOT_LOGGED_IN) {
          //this._router.navigate(['/welcome']);
        }
      } else {
        for(let ad of ads.urls) {
          let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AdvertisementComponent);

          this._componentReference =   this.adList.createComponent(componentFactory);
          //Get instance so we access the properties
          let componentInstance = this._componentReference.instance;
          componentInstance.url = ad;
        }
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Error", error);
    }, () => {
      //Always
    });
  }
```

This is my template

```
<div on-scroll='scrollHandler()'>
  <ul>
    <!-- Hack because we can't embed element -->
    <li #adList style="display: none;"></li>

    <li scroll-item><!— footer —></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to set the target as the ul element as shown below

```
<div on-scroll='scrollHandler()'>
  <ul #adList>
    <!— I want to add an element between here -->

    <!— and here —>
    <li scroll-item><!— footer —></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, my question is how do I do the equivalent of jQuery.append()?

Comment: possible naive question here, but why can't you do: `<ul #adList><advertisement *ngFor="let ad of ads.urls" [url]="ad"></advertisement><li scroll-item><!-- footer --></li></ul>`

Comment: @StevenLuke not naive at all and does the job I want. However, I need to pass more than just a URL to the component, so will play around a bit but up vote and thanks

Comment: Cool.  I wasn't sure if you didn't actually know the component you needed until runtime or something.  If there is a lot of information to be transferred, I usually use a service, and pass some identifier (index?) into the component.  The component then uses the identifier to get the correct info from the service.